# DataDog - read json file from s3 and show it in dashboard

Tags: datadog

how can I read a json file from s3 and show the content in DataDog dashboard?

DataDog agent can send metrics from servers to datadog.
Can I send the text/json file from s3 to DataDog using DataDog agent and show it in dashboard?

sample json:
{job_name:'sample_job', total_success: 10, total_failure: 3}

Comment: What is generating the logs on S3 - are they coming from the AWS services directly? Take a look at this lambda for ingesting logs from s3 https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/send-aws-services-logs-with-the-datadog-lambda-function/?tab=awsconsole

Comment: @bwest - these are the logs from third party applications which we dont have access to. So we cant install datadog agent there.

Comment: In that case, it's probably best to have a custom lambda function that can read the logs and send them to Datadog in whatever way you prefer (I'd probably use http). There should be lots of examples of code that reads JSON from S3 and sends it somewhere, depending on your language of choice.

Answer (score 1):

The Datadog Forwarder is an AWS Lambda function that ships logs https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/libraries_integrations/forwarder/ and it is maintained by Datadog

Comment: unfortunately this is limited to logs from a set of AWS services rather than arbitrary log objects in a bucket